# FFMPEG streaming in OSX via NSTask : Unknown input format : avfoundation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ffmpeg, streaming, rtmp

If i try to execute ffmpeg commands on terminal, things work fine however If i use ffmpeg binary in my xcode project and run ffmpeg command via NSTask then i get error.

Code:

```
NSString *str = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ffmpeg-new"];

NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:str];

NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
@"-f",@"avfoundation",
@"-framerate",@"30",
@"-i",@"0:0",
@"-vcodec",@"h264",
@"-acodec",@"aac",
@"-ab",@"64000",
@"-ar",@"48000",
@"-ac",@"2",
@"-f",@"flv",@"rtmp://url",nil];

[task setArguments:array];
[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];
```

**Error : unknown input format : avfoundation**

Comment: Tried your code, and it worked fine — maybe include more of your code or additional details (eg. os version, sdk used, etc.)

Comment: mac osx : 10.11.6, ffmpeg 3.1.3 sdk : 10.12

Comment: now there is no error but no streaming too